# Trying to add react app to html div, cant make it work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have just started learning to use React. I found a great guide helping me build a timeline app and I have finished building my app.

But now I can't seem to find any working guide for how to make my app actually end up in my assigned div.

https://react.dev/learn/add-react-to-an-existing-project is not working for me.

In my naive aspiring coding mind, I thought I would just be able to plop down my App.js into my html div and call it a day.

If anyone have *any* pointers at all, please share them with me.

Thanks a bunch for reading.

index.html

```
.......
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../build/static/css/main.23d6f3b2.css"/>
</head>
........

<div id="timelineApp">

</div>

<script src="../build/static/js/787.28cb0dcd.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="../build/static/js/main.aa69993b.js"></script>
</body>
.....
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('timelineApp')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use `timelineApp` div as the root element for your React app, try

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('timelineApp'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

The `ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('timelineApp'));` selects your div as the root element and then `render` method renders your react app inside your root element.

`ReactDOM.render` is no longer supported in React 18; use `ReactDOM.createRoot`.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work for me. Stupid question, do i need to run my react build some how to make it show on my index.html live server?

Comment: @SebastianMolin Depends, If you are working in an `create-react-app` directory, shell command `npm start` would run the server and create the root app. But if you are integrating another project with the react app, keep in mind that running the index.html with the VSCode live sever won't load up you web app, as you would need a development sever to serve the web app, such as npm `serve` or `webpack-dev-server`